_cext module not found when importing matplotlib
While importing matplotlib, I am getting an error like:
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.

I get this error with python 3.10, 3.11, and 3.12
Can any one help me fix this error?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please post the full traceback or error message.

Please see here, here, and here.

It is a known issue with specific versions of Maptplotlib (3.3.1, 3.5; possibly more) and Python (3.7, and 3.10; possibly more) on Windows 10.
According to Thomas A. Caswell (Matplotlib Project Lead), the issue is caused by a dependency (kiwisolver), and he suggested re-installing that if it's not been properly installed.
Nevertheless, you can still attempt to fix it with pip install msvc-runtime.
If all else fails, you can do a clean sweep by uninstalling and reinstalling.
